# Golang websocket

Tags: go, websocket, concurrency, chat

Can someone help explain what does the following code snippet mean?

```
var partner = make(chan io.ReadWriteCloser)

func match(c io.ReadWriteCloser) {
    fmt.Fprintln(c, "Waiting for a partner...")
    select {
    case partner <- c:
        // handled by the other goroutine
    case p := <-partner:
        chat(p, c)
    }
}
```

Full version:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

const listenAddr = "localhost:4000"

type socket struct {
    conn *websocket.Conn
    done chan bool
}

func (s socket) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return s.conn.Read(b)
}

func (s socket) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return s.conn.Write(b)
}

func (s socket) Close() error {
    s.done <- true
    return nil
}

var rootTemplate = template.Must(template.New("root").Parse(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Websocket Chat - Golang</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script>
            var input, output, websocket;

            function showMessage(msg) {
                var p = document.createElement("p");
                p.innerHTML = msg;
                output.appendChild(p);
            }
        
            function onMessage(e) {
                showMessage(e.data);
            }
            
            function onClose() {
                showMessage("Connection closed.");
            }
            
            function onKeyUp(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                    sendMessage();
                }
            }
            
            function sendMessage() {
                var msg = input.value;
                input.value = "";
                websocket.send(msg + "\n");
                showMessage(msg);
            }
            
            function init() {
                input = document.getElementById("input");
                input.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);
                output = document.getElementById("output");
                websocket = new WebSocket("ws://{{.}}/socket");
                websocket.onmessage = onMessage;
                websocket.onclose = onClose;
            }
            
            window.addEventListener("load", init);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Say: <input id="input" type="text"/>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
`))

func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rootTemplate.Execute(w, listenAddr)
}

func socketHandler(conn *websocket.Conn) {
    s := socket{conn: conn, done: make(chan bool)}
    go match(s)
    <-s.done
}

var partner = make(chan io.ReadWriteCloser)

func match(c io.ReadWriteCloser) {
    fmt.Fprintln(c, "Waiting for a partner...")
    select {
    case partner <- c:
        // handled by the other goroutine
    case p := <-partner:
        chat(p, c)
    }
}

func chat(a, b io.ReadWriteCloser) {
    fmt.Fprintln(a, "Found one! Say hi.")
    fmt.Fprintln(b, "Found one! Say hi.")
    errc := make(chan error, 1)
    go cp(a, b, errc)
    go cp(b, a, errc)
    if err := <-errc; err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    a.Close()
    b.Close()
    go io.Copy(b, a)
    io.Copy(a, b)
}

func cp(w io.Writer, r io.Reader, errc chan<- error) {
    _, err := io.Copy(w, r)
    errc <- err
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)
    http.Handle("/socket", websocket.Handler(socketHandler))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(listenAddr, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Don’t quite understand why this chat function can be executed when a second joiner joins chat channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the HTTP handler creates a web socket and starts waiting for another party to connect. This is because when the HTTP request is handled, the handler calls `match`, which will block on `select` because the `partner` channel is neither readable nor writeable. There is no goroutine listening from it, or sending to it.

When the second request comes, `match` is called again from another goroutine. Now there are two goroutines, and they can be *matched*. One of the goroutines can send to the `partner` channel, and the other one receives it. The object transferred is the reader-writer, which is then used for communicating between the two partners.

Comment: I’m an absolute beginner in Go  Could u elaborate on the reasons why the first `select` case (sending) is hit by one of the goroutines when a second request comes, and where is the code that sends message to `partner` channel?

Comment: A channel send/receive will block until another goroutine is ready to receive/send. Select does that on multiple channels. When two goroutines enter the select statement, one will send, and the other will receive. The select will block the first goroutine until the second comes to that select. When select runs in this case, there is no guarantee will goroutine will send and which will receive, but the runtime will match the operations.